# To get the string after . through regex in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have want to retrieve the string after. From a table pos which has values like:

```
Office.Secretary
XYZ.Manager - Liaison
ABC.Community Relations Officer
```

This should be converted to

```
Secretary
Manager - Liaison
Community Relations Officer
```

I am using this :

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (name, '..+' , 1), '.', '', 1, 1) FROM table_POS;
```

But I am getting the column details as it is.

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^[^.]+[.]', '') FROM table_POS;`

Comment: Thanks ! this worked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select regexp_replace('ABC.Community Relations Officer','([^\.]{0,}\.)(.*)','\2') from dual;
```

Try regexp group capturing.

`1-st group ([^\.]{0,}\.)` - match everything to first dot with dot.

`2-nd group (.*)` -  match everything after dot.

`'\2'` - replace whole string with value from 2nd group.

With this future you can for example change order of your groups.

```
select regexp_replace('ABC.Community Relations Officer','([^\.]{0,}\.)(.*)','\2  -- \1') from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove a chunk of string from the beginning and up to the *first* dot, you need to use a negated character class regex solution:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^[^.]+[.]', '') FROM table_POS;
```

Note that here,

- `^` - matches the start of a string
- `[^.]+` - matches 1 or more characters other than a literal dot
- `[.]` - matches a literal dot.

The whole matched substring is replaced with an empty string, and is thus removed.

If you need to remove a chunk of string up to the *last* dot, you need rock's solution, something like `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^.+[.]', '') FROM table_POS;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (It will remove after last `.`)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^.*\.' , '') FROM table_POS;
```

If you want to remove after first `.`, you can use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^.*?\.' , '') FROM table_POS;
```